# HBase HBaseAdmin.getCompactionState produces NPE

Tags: hbase

I use the java HBase 2.5.3 client to compact the table and wait for compaction to be done:

```
public static void compactTable(Admin admin, byte[] tableName) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    admin.majorCompact(TableName.valueOf(tableName));
    Thread.sleep(1000L);
    while (admin.getCompactionState(TableName.valueOf(tableName)) != CompactionState.NONE) {
        LOG.info("Compaction sleep for 5 sec");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
    }
}
```

Calling `admin.majorCompact` throws NPE inside HBase client code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getCompactionState(HBaseAdmin.java:3232)
at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HBaseAdmin.getCompactionState(HBaseAdmin.java:2434)
```